# PhpStorm: is there a drag and drop feature to include JS or CSS files?

Tags: phpstorm

[image]

What is the quickest/smartest way to include a JS file into code ?

I tried to drag and drop a JS file to source code, but it opens a new tab with the JS file.

(Same question for CSS link including)

Comment: what do you mean, include? if you drag/drop the JS file onto an html document, phpstorm should create `<script src="yourjsfile.js">`?

Comment: yes: I drag and drop the file from the LEFT panel to my editor and... phpstorm OPENs is as new tab and does not create the script src ...
I added a screenshot. When I dro pthe js file, phpstorms opens a new tab with this JS !

Comment: Which PhpStorm version are you using?

Comment: It works for HTML files only ATM (PhpStorm as well as WebStorm -- same behaviour) -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/07/webstorm-2016-2-drag-files-into-html-and-quotes-style/ . I would just use Emmet/Live Template and type `script[TAB]` to expand it into a proper `<script src=""...>` tag and just fill the path to the script.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is available since version 2016.2, it's just not working in your case as you work in a PHP file.
Open a HTML file and drag'n'drop a JS or CSS file to see it working.

PhpStorm will add in case of a JS file automatically:

```
 <script src="main.js"></script>
```

In case of a CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

For the case of an empty document it will just be inserted in the current line.
If you have an `<html>` tag it will be included within and before a `<body>` tag and if available even directly in the `<head>` tag - no matter where you leave your mouse button.

To your actual case: In order to make it work you could theoretically handle *.php files like *.html files. You can do that in `Settings -> Editor -> File Types`. But of course that's not useful as you will loose all the PHP features like auto-completion for the language etc. I guess you would need to write a feature request so that they maybe implement this for PHP files too.

BTW: drag'n'drop of images to a wished position in a `<body>` tag of a html document does also work.

EDIT: Here the link to the JetBrains blog where they explain this feature: 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/07/webstorm-2016-2-drag-files-into-html-and-quotes-style/
Thanks to *LazyOne* for sharing!